# eigenvalues of a generalization of Hadamard product matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, hadamard-product

I have a Laplacian matrix ($L$), which is positive semi-definit. Then I have this matrix

$$\Delta=\begin{bmatrix} \delta_{11} & \ldots & \delta_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\delta_{n1} & \ldots & \delta_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$
in which
$\delta_{ij}=e_ie_{j}^{T}$, and  $e_i$ is a  vector.

I need to form the following matrix, and analyze the eigenvalues.

$$\begin{bmatrix} l_{11}\delta_{11} & \ldots & l_{1n}\delta_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
l_{n1}\delta_{n1} & \ldots & l_{nn}\delta_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $l_{ij}$ is a scalar, but $\delta_{ij}$ is a matrix. This certainly looks like the Hadamard product, but the problem is that the dimensions of $L$ and $\Delta$ don't necessarily match.

Any ideas about the eigenvalues?

Comment: Is each $\delta_{ij}$ of size $n\times n$? And is your $L$ the matrix with elements $\ell_{ij}$ (thus also of size $n\times n$) ? And the $e_i$'s are any vectors?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh thanks for your comment. The size of each $\delta_{ij}$ will differ according to the size of vector $e_i$. For example, consider $e_1=[1, 0]^T$ and $e_2=[1,0,1]^T$, then $\delta_{11}$ will be $2\times 2$ whereas $\delta_{12}$ will be $2\times 3$. As for $L$, this matrix contains scalar elements $l_{ij}$. For our example, let's consider $L=\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\-1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Just checked some numerics with the e1 and e2 you gave, but different L. You get 2 evals non-zero but the relationship with spec(L) is not (yet) clear.

Comment: Thank you professor @H.H.Rugh. Can we consider $$\begin{bmatrix} l_{11}\delta_{11} & \ldots & l_{1n}\delta_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
l_{n1}\delta_{n1} & \ldots & l_{nn}\delta_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$ as a Hadamard product? We know that if $\delta_{ij}$ were scalars, that would be possible. But for this matrix, can we say the same?

Comment: I don't think so. But it may share some properties with Hadamard products because of the special form for the $\delta$-matrices

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $\hat{L}$ the augmented matrix of size $N\times N$
  where $N=d_1+\cdots + d_n$.
  Define the map $\Lambda : {\Bbb C}^n \rightarrow {\Bbb C}^N$
  by $\Lambda (c)= \left[\begin{matrix} c_1 e_1 \\
        \vdots\\ c_n e_n \end{matrix} \right]$.

The augmented matrix $\hat{L}$ maps ${\Bbb C}^N$ into ${\rm im} \Lambda$ 
  and we have $\hat{L} \Lambda c = \Lambda H c$ where
  $$  H = \left( \begin{matrix}
      \ell_{11} (e_1^T e_1) & \cdots & \ell_{1n} (e_n^T e_n) \\
      \vdots & & \vdots \\
      \ell_{n1} (e_1^T e_1) & \cdots & \ell_{nn} (e_n^T e_n) 
      \end{matrix}
      \right)
  $$
  is an $n\times n$ Hadamard matrix in the usual sense. It has the same non-zero spectrum
  as $\hat{L}$. Oddly enough it is not symmetric?

As an example consider 
  $$ e_1=
     \left[\begin{matrix} 1  \\ 0  \end{matrix} \right],
     e_2=
     \left[\begin{matrix} 1  \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right],
     Y_1=
     \left[\begin{matrix} y_{11} \\ y_{12} \end{matrix} \right],
     Y_2=
     \left[\begin{matrix} y_{21} \\ y_{22} \\ y_{23} \end{matrix} \right],
     Y=
     \left[\begin{matrix} Y_1 \\ Y_2 \end{matrix} \right] \in {\Bbb C}^5 .$$
  The last is a column vector of length $5=2+3$.
  In a similar vein we write 
     $$ X=
 \left[\begin{matrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \end{matrix} \right] \in {\Bbb C}^5 .$$
  Acting upon $X$ with our  $5 \times 5$ matrix $\hat{L}$ in question we
  get $Y=\hat{L} X$ where for each of the 'principal' components
    $$ Y_i =
   \sum_{j=1}^2 \ell_{ij} (e_i e_j) X_j =
   e_i \left( \sum_{j=1}^2 \ell_{ij}  (e_j X_j)\right)
   \in {\rm Span} \{e_i\}.$$
   So each $Y_i$ is proportional to $e_i$. In other words, $Y$ is in
   the image of the map 
     $$ \Lambda : c =
 \left[\begin{matrix}  c_1 \\ c_2 \end{matrix} \right]
 \in {\Bbb C}^2 \mapsto 
 \left[\begin{matrix}  e_1 c_1 \\ e_2 c_2 \end{matrix} \right]
 \in {\Bbb C}^5. $$
   For the non-zero eigenvalues it is enough to see how
   $\hat{L}$ acts upon this image.
  So let $X_j= e_j c_j$. Then
  $$ Y_i = 
 (\hat{L} X)_i=
 (\hat{L} \Lambda c)_i=
 e_i \sum_{j=1}^2 \ell_{ij} (e_j e_j) c_j =
 e_i \sum_{j=1}^2 H_{ij} c_j,$$
     where $H$ is the 2 by 2 matrix (in our present example):
  $$  H = 
  \left( \begin{matrix}
  \ell_{11} (e_1^T e_1) &  \ell_{12} (e_2^T e_2) \\
  \ell_{21} (e_1^T e_1) &  \ell_{22} (e_2^T e_2) 
  \end{matrix}
  \right)
  =
  \left( \begin{matrix}
  \ell_{11}  &   2 \ell_{12} \\
  \ell_{21}  &  2 \ell_{22}  
  \end{matrix}
  \right)
  $$
 Whenever  you have matrices verifying
 $\Lambda H c = \hat{L} \Lambda c$ and 
 ${\rm im} \Lambda = {\rm im} \hat{L}$ then $H$ and $\hat{L}$ will have the
 same non-zero eigenvalues (fairly easy to check).

Comment: Thank you professor @H.H. Rugh . But, can you kindly explain more? I was trying to find a relationship between $L$ and $\Delta$. I would really appreciate it if you could shed some light on this. Thanks again

Comment: Not quite sure what to say. But in the example you mentioned in a previous comment we have $e_1^T e_1=1$ and $e_2^T e_2=2$. The matrix $L$ you give then becomes $H=[1 -2; -1 2]$ ($i$th column multiplied by $e_i^Te_i$). The non-zero evals of your augmented matrix are the same as the non-zero evals of $H$ (which you may check numerically as well). Do you want more details in my calculation of $H$?

Comment: I am guessing by $\hat L$  you are referring to $$\begin{bmatrix} l_{11}\delta_{11} & \ldots & l_{1n}\delta_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ l_{n1}\delta_{n1} & \ldots & l_{nn}\delta_{nn} \end{bmatrix}$$ Is that right? As a result, you say that the nonzero eigenvalues of this matrix and $$H = \left( \begin{matrix}
      \ell_{11} (e_1^T e_1) & \cdots & \ell_{1n} (e_n^T e_n) \\
      \vdots & & \vdots \\
      \ell_{n1} (e_1^T e_1) & \cdots & \ell_{nn} (e_n^T e_n) 
      \end{matrix}
      \right)$$ are the same.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I can't understand "The augmented matrix$\hat L$ maps $\mathbb{C}^N$into ${\rm im} \Lambda$ and we have$ \hat{L} \Lambda c = \Lambda H c $". What is $c$? I am really sorry :( but I couldn't understand the map you have defined.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. I have added details for the example you mentioned in another comment